# Date between dates with time

Tags: javascript, date

http://jsfiddle.net/7vzapm49/1/

```
var startdatearr = [new Date("04 Dec 2014 14:30:00").toUTCString(), new Date("07 Dec 2014 14:30:00").toUTCString()];
var enddatearr = [new Date("05 Dec 2014 14:30:00").toUTCString(), new Date("08 Dec 2014 14:30:00").toUTCString()];
var d = new Date().toUTCString();

for (i = 0; i < startdatearr.length; i++) {
    if (startdatearr[i] <= d && d <= enddatearr[i]) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
}
```

This piece of code *used* to work, but suddenly it doesn't, even if I check the date today it seemingly says that UTC is between 4th and 5th of December 2014, but it still returns false.

Does the code not work in December, or have I been using deprecated code?

Comment: Bah, didn't warn us about all the `alert()`s right up front. I always use `console.log()` whenever possible, unless I need to pause my code until the alert is responded to.

Comment: My bad! I'm used to putting alerts everywhere because putting alerts everywhere helps you find where your code doesn't function, I'll fix the fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make it into milliseconds and then compare it. It will then work correctly. As of now you're comparing strings which I suppose follows lexical pattern.

```
var startdatearr = [+new Date("04 Dec 2014 14:30:00"), +new Date("07 Dec 2014 14:30:00")];
var enddatearr = [+new Date("05 Dec 2014 14:30:00"), +new Date("08 Dec 2014 14:30:00")];
var d = +new Date();
for (i = 0; i < startdatearr.length; i++) {
    if (startdatearr[i] <= d && d <= enddatearr[i]) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
}
```

To again convert the milliseconds to date and then showing UTC string, you could do

```
alert(new Date(d).toUTCString());
alert(new Date(startdatearr[0]).toUTCString());
alert(new Date(enddatearr[0]).toUTCString());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vzapm49/2/)

Comment: Worked like magic, I have no clue how the other kept working, but then broke when we entered December, quite odd. This will work no matter when right? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user2524703 yup. Glad to have helped you:)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are running a ToString flavor method. If this previously worked, I suspect that it only worked per chance. As the `startdatearr[i] <= d` would have been checking if strings are less than or equal to. If there is any inherit conversion taking place, that would be browser / JS implementation specific and not dependable.

What might work, *depending on your goal and needs for UTC,* is remove each call to `.toUTCString()` and just use the `Date` object returned but this will be localized to the browser's timezone (again, depending on JS implementation but I'm assuming a browser is running this code).

Answer (score 1):

In a UTC date, the first part of the string is the day of the week. For example, `"04 Dec 2014 14:30:00"` in UTC is `"Thu, 04 Dec 2014 13:30:00 GMT"`.

So when you compare `d` and `startdatearr[i]`, most of the times you only check which day of the week is the first in the alphabetical order.

So this code may works or not, dependings of the day of the week.

Comment: Uh I guess, most times I had used it was within the same day, so for example from December 1st 00:00:00 to December 1st 23:59:59, which I guess means it would still work as it would pass December 1st or go behind.